# Reading binary data from fetch response when ArrayBuffer is not present

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, arraybuffer

In a react native project i have a HTTP request that returns a binary file that i need to turn into a NodeJS Buffer object. I cannot for the life of me get this to work because `arrayBuffer` is not implemented in any form in react native and every single thing out there seems to hinge on that being present.

How can i turn a fetch response into a ANYTHING that can be accepted by Buffer? uint8array, anything.

```
 async getFirmwareDownload(firmwareVersion: FirmwareVersion): Promise<Buffer | null> {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`${this.getBaseUrl()}${firmwareVersion.url}`);
            const blob = await response.blob();
            return Buffer.from(blob);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I attempted this and while its not throwing errors trying to convert. It is not converting correctly as it is missing several hundred bytes.

```
async getFirmwareDownload(firmwareVersion: FirmwareVersion): Promise<Buffer | null> {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(`${this.getBaseUrl()}${firmwareVersion.url}`);
        const text = await response.text();
        return Buffer.from(text, 'binary');
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to do it in a VERY roundabout way by converting it to base64 data URL and then back into a Buffer. This is probably horribly inefficient but it at least generates the correct size Buffer that matches the file.

```js
function blobToBuffer(blob: Blob): Promise<Buffer> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.onload = () => {
            const data = reader.result.slice(reader.result.indexOf('base64,') + 7);
            resolve(Buffer.from(data, 'base64'));
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    });
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any other method of doing this.